# Linq SelectMany causes memory allocations for each internal set?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection

I've got a simple list of hashsets:

```
List<HashSet<TestObj>> listOfSets = new List<HashSet<TestObj>>();
```

When I iterate it manually, there is no additional memory allocation:

```
foreach(var childSet in listOfSets) {
    foreach (var neighbor in childSet) {
        // do something with neighbor
    }
}
```

However, if I do the same using Linq's `SelectMany`, it allocates memory on the Heap, once per childSet:

```
foreach(TestObj neighbor in listOfSets.SelectMany(x => x)) {
    // do something with neighbor
}
```

Any idea why it does that? Is there a way around it? Otherwise, is there another way to return an `IEnumerable<TestObj>` from a list of sets, so that it won't allocate any memory when iterating it?

Edit: It appears to have something to do with boxing. When I convert it to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TestObj>>` then direct iteration also triggers memory allocations. Any ideas what exactly is happening?

```
// This code triggers malloc for every set in listOfSets
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TestObj>> enumOfEnum = listOfSets;
foreach(var childSet in enumOfEnum) {
    foreach (var neighbor in childSet) {
        // do something with neighbor
    }
}
```

Edit: Ok, so because `SelectMany` is an extention for `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. When I call `SelectMany` on `List<HashSet<T>>`, it implicitly casts to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, and because `HashSet<T>.Enumerator` is a struct, every one of the `HashSet`s is boxed (which is normal behavior when casting a struct to an interface).

Comment: How are you measuring the memory allocation?

Comment: Unless I'm looking at the wrong code, the way `SelectMany` works doesn't look too much different: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L535-L541

Comment: No they are the same : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,535 . and Select many do returns `IEnumerable<TestObj>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0

Comment: I'm using Unity3D, and the profiler there counts memory allocations calls. If I try to implement an IEnumerator manually, like in the Linq, it still generates memory allocations. However if I just do the two fors directly, it doesn't...

Comment: Update - It appears to have something to do with boxing. When I convert it to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TestObj>> then direct iteration also triggers memory allocations. See edit at bottom of quesiton.

Comment: Hum, do you have code in the inner block or nothing? It's possible that the emptyness get  better execution in foreach where compiler optimise it away.

Comment: Unity3D: No LINQ for you! 